CodeBuild AWS Flutter missing files
so I have flutter web and when im build it from the vscode im getting all the files in the  build/web directory such as
assets       flutter.js                 icons         manifest.json canvaskit    flutter_bootstrap.js       index.html    version.json favicon.png  flutter_service_worker.js  main.dart.js
but when im building in codebuild im getting only four files
[Container] 2024/06/10 16:56:47.205093 Running command ls -la build/web total 24
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  109 Jun 10 16:56 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   17 Jun 10 16:56 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   32 Jun 10 16:56 .last_build_id
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  177 Jun 10 16:56 canvaskit
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7778 Jun 10 16:56 flutter.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8103 Jun 10 16:56 flutter_bootstrap.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3723 Jun 10 16:56 index.html

any suggestions?
P.S
im pulling from the same GitHub so for sure im not suppose to miss any files
I tried to change the biuldspec.yaml many times but its seems it just can't built it
